# NoClassDefFoundError - AppCompatDelegateImplV14

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm trying to update a project by replacing all the activities to extend from the AppCompatActivity.But my app won't start with always the same error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14

- Appcompat + Design (23.1.1)
- Play services (8.4.0)

What i tried:

1. Enabled multidex.
2. Ran the gradlew -q :projectName:dependenciev - no
   nesting/i have only exclude 'support-v4' at top level).
3. Cleaned/Rebuild
   project.

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:135)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:117)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:456)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
                                                                        at [PACKAGE NAME].StartUpActivity.onCreate(StartUpActivity.java:18)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2655)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2767)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1449)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.3.2'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "[PACKAGENAME]"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
       // --------------- release keystore info
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated', 'src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated', 'src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated', 'src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['.apt_generated', 'src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    apt {
        arguments {
            androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
            resourcePackageName '[PACKAGENAME]'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude  group: 'com.android.support' , module: 'support-v4'
}

dependencies {
    // --------- Projects
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':zxing-2.3.0:android')
    // compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    // ------------ Compile local jars
    compile files('libs/crittercism_v3_0_3_sdkonly.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-android-4.45.jar')
    compile files('libs/ormlite-core-4.45.jar')
    compile files('libs/viewpagerindicator.jar')

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile(
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.2.3'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.2.3'],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.2.3']
    )


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile ('com.android.support:design:23.1.1')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'

    apt("org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion")
    compile ("org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion")

}
```

Gradlew dependencies tree:

```
_releaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- project :facebook
+--- project :zxing-2.3.0:android
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.3
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.3
+--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.3
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.3
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.3
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
+--- com.android.support:design:23.1.1
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 (*)
\--- org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.3.2
```

SOLUTION /for me/ :
I had a `support-v4` jar in a subproject which i failed to exclude anyway.So i had to modify the sub project to exclude the jar.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, not just the first line.

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response i have updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i have only exclude 'support-v4' at top level

You are getting

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14
```

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found.

Remove **Support-v4** from `Build.gradle`

```
compile project(':android-support-v4')
```

Comment: Well i tried to exclude it manually from dependencies/projects or from configuration(as it is in the main post) it always ends with the no class def found for AppCompatDelegateImplV14.
[updated] - you can check the gradle's dependencies enlisted.

Comment: @Dokuzov remove `module: 'support-v4'` I am not sure

Comment: It's taken me long to find out , but the 'facebook' project contained the 'android-support-v4' which was causing problem.
When i was adding the project as 
`compile (project(':facebook')){
        exclude  group: 'com.android.support' , module: 'support-v4'
    }`
It didn't exclude it , i had to manually remove the jar from the module myself to see if it will work , and it did.

Comment: @Dokuzov Now move ahead .Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the heads up , once i go through everything i will update my post with some little more details and will mark your post an answer.